# Java - Unbounded classpath container Websphere V6 JRE

Tags: java

I am new to JAVA world; have worked on JSP only for few months. I have recieved code of a very large project and I am getting these two errors:

Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [WebSphere v6 JRE]'

The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved

I am not sure what do I need to download to compile this project successfully from IBM website - complete RAD or WAS.

My only task is to understand this project implementation. I won't be developing anything. Please suggest a tool to understand the code. I have downloaded nwire (never used before) but need successful compilation to use.

Comment: Do you have a version of Java 6 installed on the machine?  What is JAVA_HOME set to if so?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, remove the bad JRE and add one from your environment.

Use this panel:

[image]